# Does preserve-order=true affects parallelism of test cases

Tags: testng, testng.xml

My testng.xml file looks like -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="5" name="SUITE" parallel="classes">
    <test name="TEST" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
        <class name = "" /> ( I have around 2000 TC here)
        </classes>
        </test>
        </suite>
```

Does setting preserve order affects or hampers parallelism? Say I have 5 threads and 100 TC. Does it moves to 6th class after execution of one class is complete or it waits until all 5 threads finishes execution?

In my case for some classes which have multiple test methods I saw that class only getting executed. It seems as if test cases are executed sequentially and not parallely

Answer (score 0):

see this https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-tests one thread for one class. If class contains multiple methods then same thread will execute all those methods. preserve-order does not impact on parallel classes.